# R8: Program type already present: androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding

Im getting the above error trying to create a *release* build of my app. When doing a debug build everything is running fine.

My project has a structure as follows

- app (contains databinding)
- video sdk (contains data binding)
- another sdk (contains data binding)

Im thinking it finds multiple databinding instances which makes the above error but im not really sure how to circumvent this.

What also weird is that the app does compile when clicking run in Android studio but when trying to build from terminal its not compiling

Comment: Were you able to solve this. I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Posting few of workarounds here

1. `./gradlew clean`
2. Exclude duplicates as message `Program type already present` means there is a naming conflict.

   > ```
   > configurations {
   >     compile.exclude group: 'androidx.databinding', module: 'databinding'
   > }
   > ```

Then do sync, clean & rebuild.

Comment: I have tried to add that in the app module aswell as in the library project but im still getting: 

     Program type already present: androidx.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR

Comment: Facing the same issue @sn0ep

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but tried to create a separate module for databinding gradle and add that module into all current modules (app, video sdk, another sdk)

Module core (Gradle with "api"):

```
api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

App module and other SDKs modules will use that core module.

```
implementation project(path: ':core')
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Im not sure, how this helps my app doesnt use glide its aim facing a databinding issue

Comment: @sn0ep, the point is you have to add your data binding library in the core module and use that core module as I explained in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error and spent almost 2 days in figuring out what was causing this error. Eventually, I found out that one of my transitive SDK, which used Kotlin, did not have the following in its Gradle file.

```
kotlinOptions kotlin_options = {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

After adding this, I was able to resolve the error.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this, I am not sure but sometime release apk having problem of conflict ion

Add `multiDexEnabled true` in app gradle file.

Hope this will help!